# Best way to Deploy ASP.NET webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish, web-deployment, autodeploy

I would like to know what is the efficient way for deploying `ASP.NET` *web application*. The process that I follow to deploy are:

1. *Build* the web applicaiton
2. *Publish* the web application from `Standard Bar > Build Menu` [Selecting only the files needed to execute the application]
3. *Connect to Server* using any client software like `[WinScp]`
4. *Copy* files from local computer to server.

Just like to know is this the correct approach?

Comment: There are multiple ways to to deploy web apps and none of them are necessarily more 'correct' than any other.  Your deployment method seems logical and should work fine.

Comment: Does it work?  Are you getting an error?  There are many different ways to publish sites depending on the environment you work in.  (-I'm not asking for details).  If your process works then go with it.

Comment: @Kelix: It's working fine. I learn this approach from one of my senior at my work. But since then I have been following the same approach. Also I am not in a proper environment, unable to learn the latest techniques for development and deployment.

Comment: @fais: as a side note if you are at a company that doesn't have a "proper environment" then I'd suggest you get a computer at home, make sure IIS is installed on it and learn what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is in Visual Studio (i use 2013) using One-Click Publish.  I find it to be very easy to use and works well.  [How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in visual studio 2008:

> > 1. On the Build menu, click Publish Web Site.
> > 2. In the Publish Web Site dialog box, click the ellipsis button (…) to
> >        browse to the location to which you want to publish the Web site.
> >
> > You can write the Web site output to a local or shared folder, to an
> >     FTP site, or to a Web site that you access with a URL. You must have
> >     Create and Write permissions in the target location.
> >
> > 1. To be able to change the layout (but not the code) of .aspx files
> >        after publishing the Web site, select the Allow this precompiled site
> >        to be updateable check box.
> > 2. To name strongly named assemblies using a key file or a key container,
> >        select the Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies check box,
> >        and then click OK.
> >
> > Publishing status is displayed in the taskbar. Depending on the
> >     connection speed, the size of the site and the types of content files,
> >     publishing time can vary. When publishing is completed, the status of
> >     Publish succeeded is displayed.

Comment: Do you have any idea for Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: There is no reason anyone should still be using VS2008

Comment: @Otavio Decio: Why is that?

Comment: @fais if you are still using 2008 it has the functionality as well (although im sure it might not work as well as the newer versions)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @fais: first, there have been 3 VS releases since then (2010, 2012, 2013); however more importantly the publish options have changed somewhat over the years.